# UILocalNotification in iOS 5

Tags: ios5

I'm newbie to iOS development. I have a quick question and I couldn't find any info on Apple's Developer Community.

I'm making an app with ability to schedule tasks. I plan on using UILocalNotification to set reminders.

1. Is that the correct method or are there better ways?
2. If I set a UILocalNotification, and the user changes the task due date associated with that notification, can I change the UILocalNotification?
3. iOS 5 has the new notifications pull-down. Does UILocalNotification automatically go in there?

Cheers,
Dean

Comment: This is three questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. UIlocalNotification is better option if u know that ur schedule tasks cannot exceed 64(per app) because one app cannot schedule more than 64 notification. Also u can repeat ur tasks only at unit second, minute, hour ,daily, monthly, yearly, weekday [more in apple's developer documentation]. If u want to repeat at ur own custom time then u have to schedule more than 1 notification(e.g. twice daily at 7:00 am and 9:00 pm then two notification at 7:00 am and 9:00 pm with "repeatInterval:NSDayCalendarUnit" )
2. Yes. U can change .

   UILocalNotification *cancelThisNotification = nil;
           for (UILocalNotification *someNotification in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]) {
               if([[someNotification.userInfo objectForKey:@""] isEqualToString:@"") {
                   cancelThisNotification = someNotification;
                   someNotification = nil;
                   [someNotification release];

// if wanna cancel

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:cancelThisNotification];

// if wanna change e.g. fire date

cancelLocalNotification.firedate = [NSDate urdate];
                }

```
        }
```

// but it is better to cancel any notification

3.u can(and not if u dont want) by going to Settings => Notification and chenge ur prefernce  for ur app